# How to make Tailwind flex colum full screen, but no longer

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

My screen has a gray background with a white box on the left third.  The white box extends all the way down the screen, stopping at the padding of the outer div.  The end result is that the white box is nicely framed by a gray background.

The white box is made of two columns and the right column has a list in it.  When the list is short, the white box is framed as expected.  When the list grows however, the white box also grows and extends off the bottom of the screen.  In this case, I lose the nice framing effect on the bottom of the div.

How can I get the content in the right column to scroll instead of the white box growing? Preferably using flexbox?

The code below illustrates the short-list scenario with Tailwind CSS.

```
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-100 p-6">

<main class="flex flex-grow">

    <div class="flex w-1/3 bg-white border border-gray-200">

        <div class="w-1/2 p-4">
            <p>Let column</p>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-col w-1/2 p-4">
            <p>Right column</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</main>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the overflow to scroll you need to prevent the overflow of all parent elements. In your case the outermost div should be given a `max-h-screen` and `overflow-hidden`, and your `main` element and parent div to the right column both need `overflow-hidden` as well. Then your `ul` can be given `flex-1` and `overflow-y-auto` and as soon as the content exceeds the height of the parent you should get scroll bars. This is assuming you want right column to have a header and the list itself to be scrollable, if you want the header to scroll with the list you can just wrap a div around them both.

Here is your example with the above changes on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/iYcSWqYkai

```html
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen max-h-screen overflow-hidden bg-gray-100 p-6">
  <main class="flex flex-grow overflow-hidden">
      <div class="flex w-1/3 bg-white border border-gray-200">

          <div class="w-1/2 p-4">
              <p>Left column</p>
          </div>

          <div class="flex flex-col w-1/2 p-4 overflow-hidden">
              <p>Right column</p>
              <ul class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
                  <li class="py-20">Item 1</li>
                  <li class="py-20">Item 2</li>
                  <li class="py-20">Item 3</li>
                  <li class="py-20">Item 4</li>
                  <li class="py-20">Item 5</li>
                  <li class="py-20">Item 6</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </main>
</div>
```